# How to disable the return button without clearing the URL current address

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I tried several variations for this:
non of them is what I need, some just let go back.
How can I prevent the user from going back after he was redirect to `http://localhost:3000/home` but the URL must to stay on '/home',  and the user shouldn’t be able to navigate by manually changing the address bar.

(It's actually preventing from going back to sign-up)

 These are examples I checked from other's questions.
Non of these worked.

```js
useEffect(() => {  //Non of these worked
 window.history.replaceState(null, null, '/');

 Or

 window.addEventListener('popstate', () => {
      history.go(1);
    });

Or

 window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
      history.pushState(null, document.title, window.location.href);

Or 

  window.onpopstate = function () {
    history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
    history.go(1);
}, []);`
```

After these the last address might stay `signup/mobile`, then going back will give a mixed - a wrong address with missing buttons/CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a react-router Guard to prevent the user from accessing the login component if he is authenticated which means that the authentification component needs to be protected by condition.

Exemple :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const GuardedRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        auth === true
            ? <Redirect to='{location.pathname}' />
            : <Component {...props} />
    )} />
)

export default GuardedRoute
```

Answer inspired by [How to create guarded routes for your React-App](https://blog.netcetera.com/how-to-create-guarded-routes-for-your-react-app-d2fe7c7b6122)

Comment: Hi Hajed, what  are the `auth` and `rest` and where are they defined ?

Comment: I'm confused with the `<Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/' />`

Comment: Hello ExtraSun, this is just an example,  the "auth" it's a boolean object to verify if the user is authenticated or not, and the "...rest" represents extra properties for the route (consider it as etc a.k.a "..." .

Comment: The idea is to change the authentication component route to a guarded route  just like the example above so if the user is authenticated he can't access  back the login component which means he will stay  in the current pathname and I think it's exactly what you need if the user is authenticated when the return button is clicked redirect it to the current route /home ({location.pathname}) without clearing the URL  ( and not the login route).

Comment: I tried that it didn't worked. black page. My App.js has `Switch` and `Route`.  `<Route exact path='/signup'>
 <SignUp setUserNumber={setUserID} setIfSignUp={setIfSignUp} />
  </Route>
 <Route exact path='/home'>
 <Home userIDNumber={userID} setIfSignUp={setIfSignUp} />
 </Route>`     (many properties),          How can I combine them two ?

Comment: you already did in the SinUp !, Could you plz update your question with more info about your current state coz technically the guarded route solves the problem in your case. you are missing some details in the implementation. plz refer to the " How to create guarded routes for your React-App" link above to get it right.

Comment: I visited the link, tried to fix my App.jsc but didn’t get it, how this GourdRoute is working. Can we continue tomorrow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235033/discussion-between-extrasun-and-hajed-kh).

Comment: The path doesn't change, how can I replace it inside `GuardedRoute ` ?